# Using different config for seeds in Laravel

Tags: laravel

When I seed my database, I would like to use the *null* `BROADCAST_DRIVER`. I tried setting the config var `config('broadcasting.default', null);` in  *DatabaseSeeder.php*. However, the seeders are still using the driver defined in *.env*.

How do I use a different `BROADCAST_DRIVER` for my seeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax. Set it with:

```
config(['broadcasting.default' => 'null'])
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, the *null* driver actually has to be a string, i.e. *'null'*.